# Return statement in a handler of function-try-block of a constructor

Tags: c++

Please help with an example to understand below

From C++ n45277 : $15.3 - 13

> If a `return` statement appears in a handler of the function-try-block of a constructor, the program is ill-formed.

does this mean using `return` in constructor  ??

Thanks

Comment: `T() try : x()  { return; } catch (...) {}`

Comment: "_does this mean using return in constructor"_ - No, it doesn't. You should learn what a function level try block is first.

Comment: No: `int f() try { return 1; } catch (...) { /* return here is ill-formed */ }

Comment: @Dieter Possibly, but that's not a constructor as specified in the text cited in the question.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Your return is in the body, not the handler.

Comment: @AlanStokes True, it's just an variation of 0x499602D2's comment

Comment: @Dieter  int f() try { return 1; } catch (...) { /* return here is ill-formed */ }   - is a ordinary function not a constructor , i think return statement is valid in catch {} and try {} , but where as in function-try-block of a constructor return is valid only in try{} but not in handler (catch{}) :  $6.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [function-try-block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block) is a `try` block that wraps *outside* the entire body of a function or constructor, rather than just a section of code *inside* of the body.

In the case of a constructor, it allows you to catch an exception that is thrown while initializing base classes and data members within the *initialization list*.  If such an exception is thrown, you can `catch` it and process the error as needed, but you cannot `return` from the `catch` block.  When execution reaches the end of the `catch` block, the current exception is automatically rethrown.  Before the `catch` is entered, any base class and data member that was successfully constructed before the initial exception was thrown has already been destructed to prevent leaks.

As the standard says:

> If a `return` statement appears in a handler of the function-try-block of a constructor, the program is ill-formed.

In this case, the *handler* is referring to a `catch` block of the `try` block.

For example:

```
int checkValue(int value)
{
    if (value == 1)
        throw std::runtime_error("illegal value");
    return value;
}

struct A
{
    std::string str;
    int value;

    A(int i) try : str("hello"), value(checkValue(i))
    {
        // constructor body here ...
        // 'return' is OK here!
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // do something here (log the error, etc)...
        // 'return' is illegal here!
    }
};
```

Notice how the `try` is before the *initialization list*, and the *body* of the constructor is inside of the `try` block.

If `checkValue()` throws an exception, the construction of `A` is aborted, automatically destructing `str` in the process.

You could accomplish the same thing without using a *function-try-block*:

```
int checkValue(int value)
{
    if (value == 1)
        throw std::runtime_error("illegal value");
    return value;
}

struct A
{
    std::string str;
    int value;

    A(int i)
    {
        try
        {
            str = "hello";
            value = checkValue(i);
            // 'return' is OK here!
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            // do something here (log the error, etc)...
            // 'return' is OK here! But then the constructor
            // would not be aborted...
            throw;
        }
    }
};
```

Where *function-try-block* is commonly used is when you want to catch/log exceptions that are thrown in things that *cannot* be invoked inside the normal constructor *body*, only in the *initialization list*, such as base class constructors and data member constructors.